# I am tring to update the data in DB but it's not working

Tags: java, jdbc

i am trying to update the data in the doctor table in the DB,but it's not working ps.executeUpdate()==1 return false.

i tried changing the query but it's not worked

this is the java code

```
public boolean userDataChangeSave(String employee,String nic,String dob,String name,String address,String mobile,String email,String regNo) throws SQLException {

        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/easymedi","root","password");
        String query="update "+employee+" set nic=?,dob=?,name=?,address=?,mobile=?,email=? where regNo=?";
        //String q2="update doctor set nic='blah',name='blahblah' where regNo='002'";
        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);

        ps.setString(1,nic);
        ps.setDate(2,Date.valueOf(dob));
        ps.setString(3,name);
        ps.setString(4,address);
        ps.setString(5,mobile);
        ps.setString(6,email);
        ps.setString(7,regNo);

        if(ps.executeUpdate()==1){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

i am trying to update the data in the table but it's not working

Comment: Are you sure that the employee exists in the database?

Comment: yha there is a table called doctor.

Comment: when i try to use "update doctor set nic="blah".... where regNo="001" ;" it's woks

Comment: Yes it would work because the SQL update query is "UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;"

Comment: but when i try that way it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect SQL Syntax. The right syntax is -

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

What you are doing is updating the table whose name is the value of employee variable. Suppose you pass employee value as "Adam", then it would try to update the table Adam which does not exist. Instead use

```
String query="update doctor set nic=?,dob=?,name=?,address=?,mobile=?,email=? where regNo=?";
```

Comment: there are multiple tables with different employees that why i use employee variable

Answer (score 0):

How positive are you that you're working with doctor who has a regNo = '002'? Have you ran a select statement to make sure '002' exists?

If you've ran your code successfully and it updated with '001', that shows your syntax is accurate.

I'd also refactor it a tad and hard code the doctor table in:

```
public boolean userDataChangeSave(String nic,String dob,String name,String address,String mobile,String email,String regNo) throws SQLException {

        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/easymedi","root","password");
        String query="update doctor set nic=?,dob=?,name=?,address=?,mobile=?,email=? where regNo=?";
        //String q2="update doctor set nic='blah',name='blahblah' where regNo='002'";
        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);

        ps.setString(1,nic);
        ps.setDate(2,Date.valueOf(dob));
        ps.setString(3,name);
        ps.setString(4,address);
        ps.setString(5,mobile);
        ps.setString(6,email);
        ps.setString(7,regNo);


        return ps.executeUpdate() == 1;
    }
```

Comment: yha there is a regNo="002"